# li elements not working with ng-repeat when data extends to 2nd row

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pagination

[image]

Hi, I have implemented pagination in my project with the help of angular js. I use anchor elements inside li elements to represent the page numbers. The li elements are displayed using ng-repeat. If the total no. of pages in less than 20 all the li elements are displayed in a single row and everything works fine. But if the no. of pages increase, the li elements extend to the next row. The issue is that the pages in the first row are working fine but the pages in the 2nd row are not clickable although they are also  elements. Below is the code I have written.

```
<li ng-repeat="n in paginationParam.range" 
    ng-class="{active: n == paginationData.currentPage}">
    <a ng-click="setPage(n)" style="cursor:pointer">{{n+1}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: might be some `z-index` issue.. Could you try to replicate in `fiddle` or `plunker`?

Comment: yes it was a height issue, fixed it by adding style="height: auto;"